Android app in Kotlin + IntelliJ: my view object will not completely fill itself in paint unsure on solution
See below for code block, I have a view object which is supposed to get the values of the grids size then draw a rectangle and colour it blue, then draw circles at certain points in the rectangle, while it does draw as so, it doesnt fill up the view object's size I have created which covers the whole screen, instead it stops when the circle quota has been met, I want it to fill the view object with the rectangle and circles
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        recalculateDimensions(w, h)
    }

    private fun recalculateDimensions(w: Int, h: Int) {
        val diameterX = w / (colCount + (colCount + 1) * circleSpacingRatio)
        val diameterY = h / (rowCount + (rowCount + 1) * circleSpacingRatio)

        circleDiameter = minOf(diameterX, diameterY)
        circleSpacing = circleDiameter * circleSpacingRatio
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        val gridLeft = 0f
        val gridTop = 0f
        val gridRight: Float = gridLeft + colCount * (circleDiameter+circleSpacing) + circleSpacing
        val gridBottom: Float = gridTop + rowCount * (circleDiameter+circleSpacing) + circleSpacing

        canvas.drawRect(gridLeft, gridTop, gridRight, gridBottom, gridPaint)

        val radius = circleDiameter/2f

        for (row in 0 until rowCount) {
            // The vertical center is the same for each circle in the row
            val cy = gridTop + circleSpacing + ((circleDiameter + circleSpacing) * row) + radius

            for (col in 0 until colCount) {
                // We will later on want to use the game data to determine this
                val paint = noPlayerPaint

                // Drawing circles uses the center and radius
                val cx = gridLeft + circleSpacing + ((circleDiameter + circleSpacing) * col) + radius

                canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint)
            }
        }
    }

I've tried a bunch of ai solutions lol, also tried removing circle spacing values but it just removed the extra padding of colour after a circle was drawn on the end.
